# CakePhp model find with association

Tags: cakephp, model, associations

it seemed to be, that i am too stupid. I read the documentation and maaaaany questions here and in other forums but i am still not able to get a find-method with an association to run...
It seemed to be that there is a beginners mistake...

Ok here is the code:

**ScriptParam-Model:**

```
class ZToolScriptParam extends ScriptBuilderAppModel {
public $useTable ="z_tool_script_params";
public $primaryKey = "script_param_id"; 

 public $script_id;
public $parameter_name= "";
public $parameter_type= "";
 public $parameter_len= "";
public $parameter_right_len= "";

public $belongsTo = array(
    'ScriptBuilder.ZToolScript' => array(
        'className' => 'ScriptBuilder.ZToolScript',
        'foreignKey' => 'script_id',
    )
);
public $validate = array(

);

}
```

**Script-Model:**

```
class ZToolScript extends ScriptBuilderAppModel {
public $useTable ="z_tool_scripts";
public $primaryKey = "script_id";

public $script_name= "";
public $script_path= "";
public $script_file= "";

public $validate = array(
    'script_name' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty'
    ),

);
public $hasMany = array(
    'ScriptBuilder.ZToolScriptParam' => array(
        'className' => 'ScriptBuilder.ZToolScriptParam',
        'foreignKey' => 'script_id',
        'dependent' => false
    )
);
}
```

I expect when call the find-method, that i get the models and the associated models.

```
$scripts = $this->ZToolScript->find('all');
```

but I don't get the associated model:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ZToolScript] => Array
            (
                [script_name] => test_sp2
                [script_path] => \webroot\scripte\
                [script_file] => test_sql.txt
                [script_id] => 1
            )

    )
```

I expect that i made a simple mistakes but unfortunately i didn't see the mistake. Can anybody help me?

Greetz

V

**EDIT: 1**

I correct the link of "ZToolScript".

**EDIT: 2**

Add the table-schema of the models:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[z_tool_scripts](
    [script_name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [script_path] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [script_file] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) 
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.z_tool_scripts
   ADD script_id INT IDENTITY   

ALTER TABLE dbo.z_tool_scripts
   ADD CONSTRAINT PK_z_tool_scripts
   PRIMARY KEY(script_id)
GO
------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[z_tool_script_params](
    [parameter_name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [parameter_type] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [parameter_len] [int] NULL,
    [parameter_right_len] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [script_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [change_date] [date] NULL)

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.z_tool_script_params
   ADD script_param_id INT IDENTITY 

ALTER TABLE dbo.z_tool_script_params
   ADD CONSTRAINT PK_z_tool_script_params
   PRIMARY KEY(script_param_id)

ALTER TABLE dbo.z_tool_script_params
add constraint z_tool_script_params_script_id_FK FOREIGN KEY ( script_id ) references  z_tool_scripts(script_id)
```

**EDIT 3:**

Ok that's realy a long question:
I have an other but similar problem. I try to create a many-to-many-assiciation:

```
<?php
App::uses('ProjectAdminAppModel', 'ProjectAdmin.Model');
class ZToolProject extends ProjectAdminAppModel {
public $useTable ="z_tool_project_steps";
public $primaryKey = "id";
public $name= "";
public $desc = "";
public $activ_step = true;
public $order = 0;
public $project_id;

public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'ZToolScript' =>
        array(
            'className' => 'ScriptBuilder.ZToolScript',
            'joinTable' => 'z_tool_psteps_scripts',
            'foreignKey' => 'step_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'script_id',
            'unique' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'with' => ''
        )
);
}
```

The connected Script-Model is the same than descriped above.
Here are the fruther Create-SQL-Scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[z_tool_project_steps](
[name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[desc] [text] NULL,
[activ_step] [bit] NULL,
[order] [int] NULL,
[project_id] [int] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.z_tool_project_steps
   ADD id INT IDENTITY  

ALTER TABLE dbo.z_tool_project_steps
   ADD CONSTRAINT PK_z_tool_projects_steps
   PRIMARY KEY(id)

ALTER TABLE dbo.z_tool_project_steps
add constraint z_tool_project_steps_project_id_FK FOREIGN KEY ( project_id ) references z_tool_projects(id)

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[z_tool_psteps_scripts](
    [step_id] [int] NULL,
    [script_id] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.z_tool_psteps_scripts
   ADD con_id INT IDENTITY  

ALTER TABLE dbo.z_tool_psteps_scripts
   ADD CONSTRAINT PK_z_tool_psteps_scripts
   PRIMARY KEY(con_id)

ALTER TABLE dbo.z_tool_psteps_scripts
add constraint z_tool_psteps_scripts_script_id_FK FOREIGN KEY ( script_id ) references z_tool_scripts(script_id)

ALTER TABLE dbo.z_tool_psteps_scripts
add constraint z_tool_psteps_scripts_step_id_FK FOREIGN KEY ( step_id ) references z_tool_project_steps(id)
```

The Problem seemed to be the same. I also get no associations with the normal find-method. Is it a primary-Key-problem? I can't imagine, that here is such a big problem. Pleeeeeease can anybody help me???

Comment: your `ZToolScripts` model is linked with `ZToolScripts` Model, is this actually what you're trying to achieve? If so your table isn't right.

Comment: Oh, yes that was wrong... i correct the link as it should be. But i still don't get the associated Model.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem but... why are you using plural names for your models and not singular names as requested by cake conventions? Also: do you get any warning?

Comment: Hmm, i don't realy know... there was no direct reason for the plural. I know the conventions...No don't get any warnings and i have the debug-mode "2". It seemed to be that cake don't know, that there is any association. Perhaps I should mention that I use mssql. I also create a foreign-key relationship in the databases by myself. But nothing helps. :(

Comment: Have you tried with `ContainableBehavior`?

Comment: can you post your tables schemas?

Comment: No i haven't tried the ContainableBehavior, I would also be possible with a join-configuration... but i know that cake can do this without any further configuration, so don't know why should do it more complicated than it must be. @arilia: i add the creates of the tables in the database in the first post. But i thought it not that important because the cake-model-configuration is the important thing. Is it possible to generate the tables of the cake-model-definition? I know many other frameworks that can do this, but not with cake.

Comment: I think you don't need to add the path to the plugin in your association. Try this: `public $hasMany = array(
    'ZToolScriptParams' => array( ... ) );`

Comment: No, nothing changes. I think it's totaly unimportant because it's only a name where i could call the assoziated models... I realy don't know where my mistake is.. Is there any further configuration in cake, that i should define how deep the assoziation should go? Or something like this?

Comment: OK, i found an other hint, but i still don't know the solution. I found out, that the defined association in the model is still empty. If I debug the whole Model ZToolScript the array "hasMany" is empty. But I don't know why!!? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

OK, i found my problem. It wasn't displayed on the code which is shown above.... My problem was, that i load the models like:

```
$this->loadModel("ZToolScript");
```

The problem was, that the model is in a plugin, so i have to define the plugin like:

```
$this->loadModel("ScriptBuilder.ZToolScript");
```

I didn't have remarked that problem because anything else run without a problem only the associations...

Perhaps that helps any other person.

Greetz

V